# Finding Perl modules already packaged for Debian and Redhat

Tags: perl, package, debian, redhat

I'm investigating making a Perl application that uses many modules into either a Debian and/or Redhat package. Currently, I believe the 'cleanest' way to do this is to cite, where possible, the modules that are packaged already for the given distribution.

The alternative would be to use CPAN and probably have some duplications, problems with @INC etc.

However, I can find or interrogate a list of Debian packages here: http://pkg-perl.alioth.debian.org/cpan2deb/ but I can't currently find an equivalent for Redhat/Fedora. Also I don't really know whether cpan2deb is authoritative and up to date.

If there's another clean way to do this, I'd welcome any other ideas too.

Answer (score 3):

The Debian Perl Group is your best bet on the Debian world. Not only do they intercept all spread modules packages for Debian but they also try to keep them up to date.

See this page:

http://qa.debian.org/developer.php?login=pkg-perl-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org

Answer (score 1):

There is [cpanspec](http://cpanspec.sourceforge.net/) but it's not been touched in a few years.  I seem to remember cpan2rpm but I don't have much experience with that one.

Answer (score 1):

> > The alternative would be to use CPAN and probably have some duplications, problems with @INC etc.

I've got a perl program packaged for debian with a large number of dependencies. For expediency, I've chosen a grubby hybrid approach with some packaged modules as dependencies, plus a cheat backdoor CPAN install, which runs from my post-installation script. I hive a copy of my application's META.yml, then recheck my dependencies.

1.`debian/rules` file makes a copy of META.yml:

```
 override_dh_auto_install:
dh_auto_install; \
cp META.yml etc/;\
```

2.`debian/libmyapp-perl.install` then installs META.yml:

```
etc/META.yml /usr/share/myapp/etc/
```

3.`debian/libmyapp-perl.postinstall` then cross-checks dependencies:

```
echo "Cross checking with cpan";
for m in `perl -Mstrict -MYAML::Syck -e'my $r = YAML::Syck::LoadFile("/usr/share/myapp/etc/META.yml")->{requires}; for (grep {$_ ne "perl"} (sort keys %$r)) {eval "use $_ $r->{$_}"; print "$_\n" if $@}'`; do
   # would prefer App::cpanminus, but that's not packaged for debian either?
   PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT=1 perl -MCPAN -e "install $m";
 done
```

Not exactly clean, but a quick approach to installing a mix of dependent debian packages plus a few CPAN modules.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for this, unhappily, given the state of the 'world' we may end up with a similar idea...

Comment: Hi Hugh. I've found that there's always a percentage of modules which either aren't packaged, or you need the more recent version. Building and maintaining your own local packages can be a real drag and you really also need to maintain your own debian repository to do it properly.